# SwiftUI & MVVM: How to animate "list elements change" when view model changes the "data source" (`@Publish items`) itself

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am still relatively new to SwfitUI and Combine so maybe I am trying to do something very incorrectly but I just cannot see how to achieve what I am aiming to do with SwiftUI and MVVM.
Here is the scenario:

- `ViewModel` class with a property `@Published var items = [String]()`
- Main view (HomeView) that has a `ForEach` showing the items from its view model
- HomeView has a `@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel`
- The `HomeView` `ForEach` uses the `items` from viewModel
- `ViewModel` changes the `items` (in my case core data changes)
- The `HomeView` `ForEach` reflects the change immediately

This all works, but what I want to do is animate the elements in the `ForEach` changing due to the `viewModel.items` changing.

What I can do is `import SwiftUI` into the `ViewModel` and use `withAnimation` to wrap the setting of new `items`. But this beats the purpose of the ViewModel as it now has a direct reference to UI code.

Here some code I have:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
         ForEach(items) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI // This should not be imported as it breaks MVVM patter

class ViewModel {
    @Published var items = [String]()

    func onItemsChanged(_ newItems: [String]) {
       withAnimation { // This works but will break MVVM patter
          items = newItems
       }
    }
}
```

Any ideas if this can be achieve to make MVVM happy and work with SwiftUI?

Comment: Your View can observe some bool property at your ViewModel with Toggle e.g. Toggle("", isOn: $viewModel.someBoolProperty). This way you transfer the work to VIEW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add animation to the container which hold your view items, like below

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {                      // << container
     ForEach(items) { item in
        Text(item)
    }
  }
  .animation(.default)          // << animates changes in items
}
```

See next posts for complete examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893462/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776506/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63364795/12299030.

Comment: `.animation(Animation?)` has been deprecated with iOS 15. For iOS 16 you now need to use `.animation(Animation?, value: Equatable)`. So it would be `.animation(.default, value: items)`. You can stack multiple animation modifiers on one View and you need to specify this animation modifer for each property that you want to be animated.